# Web.config file not found after projects moved

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, specflow

I have a bunch of web projects in `Visual Studio` that I moved from the C: drive to the D: drive.

I,

- updated `IIS` to point to the new locations
- done an `IIS` Reset
- restarted the computer
- cleared all the folders mentioned on [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/clean-up-after-visual-studio) page
- cleaned all my solutions
- rebuilt all solutions and so forth.

And yet when I run any `SpecFlow` test I get a `HTTP 500` error, with the root cause being that it can't find the `web.config` file of one of the solutions because it is looking for it on the C: drive rather than the D: drive.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Is this any help? http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Configuration/

Comment: I've now regenerated the feature files as suggested here but that didn't do it.

Comment: Just to clarify what your problem is, you are getting an HTTP 500 error for the web site being tested? When you moved the files, did you check the file permissions to ensure IIS has read/write and execute permissions? For my Windows 7 box, I need to grant permissions to IUSR and IIS_IUSRS in order for that application in IIS to fire up correctly.

Comment: It's a 500 on a project that is not a website but is used by the website.

Comment: I Would search the whole solution for the text C: using grep or similar. That'll probably be the quickest solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think Chrome is your web browser? This is the default error page Chrome displays when it receives a 500 HTTP response from the server with no content.

Run the site directly on the server – depending on the configuration of your site/server, you may be able to see the real error if you load the site from a browser located on the same server.  You may need to turn off ‘show friendly http errors.’
Temporarily add the following within the appropriate tags in your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="true" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

After you have added those, load the page again to see if you can get a more detailed error.

Comment: The point is though, that Specflow reports that there is a Configuration Error and then refers to the path of the web.config file, which starts with C:\ rather than D:\.